# BC Break Symfony 3.3 to 3.4?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3, symfony-3.4

I recently upgraded my Symony application from version 3.3 to 3.4.

In my legacy code, I have a completely overriden SwitchUserListener class (for impersonation). When running the cache clear command, the following exception has been thrown.

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\OutOfBoundsException] 
Service "security.authentication.switchuser_listener.main": The index "9" is not in the range [0, 8].
```

This is caused because some DI logic and a new argument have been added to the constructor of the base SwitchUserListener in 3.4, breaking BC.
(file : https://github.com/symfony/security-http/blob/3.4/Firewall/SwitchUserListener.php#L54, commit : https://github.com/symfony/security-http/commit/f1720c6dd0844450cd134e2a5fc8319f492d56f1#diff-3eea7218d9978bdd41e254e67047ca92)

How would you handle this case of BC break?
Because everything in the base SwitchUserListener class is private, i had no other idea but to create my own class instead of overriding the default one.

For now, I will update my class, but I would like to know how to avoid a similar case in the future. Any ideas?

Here is a sample of my class :

```
class SwitchUserListener implements ListenerInterface
{
    private $tokenStorage;
    private $provider;
    private $userChecker;
    private $providerKey;
    private $accessDecisionManager;
    private $resourceMapper;
    private $usernameParameter;
    private $role;
    private $apiScheme;

    /**
     * @var ClientManager
     */
    private $clientManager;

    public function __construct(
        TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage,
        UserProviderInterface $provider,
        UserCheckerInterface $userChecker,
        $providerKey,
        AccessDecisionManagerInterface $accessDecisionManager,
        ResourceMapper $resourceMapper,
        $usernameParameter = '_switch_user',
        $role = 'ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH',
        $apiScheme = 'http'
    ) {
        if (empty($providerKey)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('$providerKey must not be empty.');
        }

        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->provider = $provider;
        $this->userChecker = $userChecker;
        $this->providerKey = $providerKey;
        $this->accessDecisionManager = $accessDecisionManager;
        $this->resourceMapper = $resourceMapper;
        $this->usernameParameter = $usernameParameter;
        $this->role = $role;
        $this->apiScheme = $apiScheme;
    }

    public function setClientManager(ClientManager $clientManager)
    {
        $this->clientManager = $clientManager;
    }

/** My own logic here, using private attributes **/
}
```

Thanks.

Edit :

This is the line that makes BC break.
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L723

Comment: Had the same problem, solved it by reevaluating my previous solution and found another way using the switch_user event. But i can see use-cases where this might be an unfitting strategy. Depends on the custom logic really.

Comment: Yes, my admin website is hosted in another application which has nothing to do with the front application. So the base SwitchUserListener is completely irrelevant for me, and i need to create one from scratch.

Comment: Adding new optional parameter is not considered as a BC break. To avoid such case in future use a Decorator pattern. Create new POPO class implementing the interface and require original Symfony class in the constructor.

Comment: Hello @Mike . Indeed, adding a new optional parameter is not considered as a BC break. But this optional parameter should not be accessed by the DI when trying to inject parameters on runtime. It is not the fact that the parameter has been added that makes it a BC breaker, but rather the fact that no check is done before doing this https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L723.